# Определение грамматической основы

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, основа, союзные-слова

*Я люблю город, **который** заставляет меня вспоминать прошлое.*
Скажите, пожалуйста, в этом предложении "который" — это подлежащее или сказуемое?

Comment: Катя, на сайте принято благодарить участников за все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов на свой вопрос галочкой.

Answer (score 2):

[КОТОРЫЙ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9)
**II. *союзн. сл.*** **1.** Связывает определительное придаточное предложение с главным, определяя в нём какое-либо существительное или местоимение. *Вот те люди, которые спасли вас.*

*Я люблю город, **который*** [= город] ***заставляет** меня **вспоминать** прошлое.*

В придаточной части сложноподчинённого предложения союзное слово *который* выступает в роли подлежащего; *заставляет вспоминать* — это составное глагольное сказуемое.
*Который* отвечает на вопрос "что?" и указывает на то, что дей­ствие "заставляет вспоминать" производит город (о нём говорилось в главной части).