# Пунктуация в уточняющих членах преложения

Tags: пунктуация

"Производством посуды славилась заволжская, или керженская земля".

"Или керженская" — это уточняющий член предложения, который выделяется запятыми? Но почему выделяется именно "керженская земля", а не просто "керженская"? Уточнение именно в названии должно быть?
Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Катя, на сайте принято благодарить участников за все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов на свой вопрос галочкой. Вы пока не отметили ни одного ответа.

Comment: Катя, спасибо, что прислушались к совету. А чем Вам не понравился [**этот ответ**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470805/Определение-грамматической-основы/470808#470808)? Совершенно правильный и отлично оформленный.

Answer (score 2):

Указанный вами член предложения — не уточняющий, а пояснительный.
См. [здесь](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-), часть Б, пункт 2:

> Пояснительные члены предложения могут присоединяться союзом *или* (в
> значении «то есть»):
>
> *Это был Александр Тимофеевич, или попросту Саша, приехавший из Москвы*
> (Чехов).

И далее:

> Примечание. Определения, носящие характер пояснения (перед ними можно
> поставить слова *а именно, то есть*), отделяются запятой от поясняемого
> слова, но после них запятая обычно не ставится.

Точных примеров с *или* там нет, но на основании этих двух пунктов можно сделать вывод: в вашем случае запятая перед "земля" не требуется.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Оригинал:**

*Деревянную посуду производили во многих местах: в Сергиево-Посадском и в Кирилло-Белозерском монастырях, в московских, ярославских, тверских, костромских и калужских землях. Но особо славилась **заволжская**, или, как ее еще называли, **керженская**.*

Предложение из учебного текста: *Производством посуды славилась **заволжская, или керженская земля.***

Разница, причем существенная, есть.

2. **Розенталь.** [**§ 23. Пояснительные конструкции**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119), пункт 2.

*Такие эмоционально-оценочные, **или, иначе, лирические,** эпитеты встречаются и у других поэтов.*

А если убрать "иначе", то запятую надо ставить? *Такие эмоционально-оценочные, **или лирические**, эпитеты встречаются и у других поэтов.*

3. Пояснительные определения бывают разные. Если речь идет **о терминах**, обозначающих два названия **в форме прилагательных,** то можно предположить, что  запятая ставится.

Так что вопрос остается **открытым:** надо поискать предложения с такими терминами.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Итак, вопрос закрываем: второй пример из той же темы Розенталя точно повторяет структуру заданного предложения: *Отметим два вида возбуждающей, **или входной,** функции.*

А Розенталь – это авторитетные правила, на которые всегда можно дать ссылку для доказательства. (Спасибо нашему участнику Александру С. за подсказку).

Итак, правильный ответ: *Производством посуды славилась заволжская, **или керженская**, земля.*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136442/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----).

Comment: @Nektoid Я могу признать, что составные имена собственные в некоторых темах могут писаться с прописной буквы,  и тогда в середине текста кавычки, конечно же,  не нужны. Но при этом читатель хорошо понимает границы названия (там как бы стоят «невидимые» пограничные кавычки). И  если после такого названия поставить запятую, то она будет относиться к структуре предложения – в частности, обозначать присоединительную часть текста. Это все верно, но данный пример не подходит к обсуждаемой теме. В нашем случае два топонимических названия являются определениями в сочетании с существительным «земля»